# C Image Library

Tags: c, image, playstation-portable

Can anyone recommend a decent C image library?

I'm after loaders for bmp, gif, jpg, png and tga.

I want to use this for programming my **Sony Playstation Portable**, so opensource would be very handy.

After some googleing I've found FreeImage and CImg, but both feel rather heavy, and CImg is C++ not C.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you control the images you're loading, the lightest loader I know is Sean Barrett's awesome [stb_image.c](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c) (direct link to single file source code!).

There are also other very worthwhile libraries on Sean's site such as a tiny TrueType rasterizer and Vorbis decompressor, btw.

If you need OpenGL image loading that uses stb_image, I'll humbly point you to [SOILex](http://bitbucket.org/akx/soilex)...

Answer (score 13):

ImageMagick has a [C API to connect to its libraries](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php). There's also what they call a ["low-level interface" between C and the ImageMagick libraries](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php).

Comment: But how portable is it for the PSP.

Answer (score 4):

I used [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) for PSP games in the past, but it was for pre-processing the data rather than in-game.

Answer (score 3):

[DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) is often recommended. Whether or not it does what you want, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I will second Thomas Owens's ImageMagick suggestion.  It is mind-boggling just how comprehensive the library is, and how much time it saves you in the end.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/kgui/source/browse/trunk/kguiimage.cpp) is some code I wrote for handling images. It is in c++ ( not c ) but you should be able to easily extract the BMP and GIF load code. It's licensed LGPL.

I use the libpng and jpeglib for decompressing those formats.

Answer (score 1):

For one of my project, I am using [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) Library. It's very useful to start with. Moreover, they also have a decent documentations.