# Simple C image library?

Tags: c, image, image-processing

What's the simplest C image library for loading and saving?  I just want a 2D array to test some algorithms, and built-in functions are not needed.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec. Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079/c-image-library

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All these libraries are way too complicated for me.  In your place I'd grit my teeth, define an abstraction for a dynamic two-dimensional array, and I'd read and write [plain ASCII PNM format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html).

Comment: I have done the same before to test some image processing algorithms. It is very easy. Just write header (in ascii) and put you pixel data after.

Comment: this is wat i ended up doing, using convert to switch between fmts

Answer (score 7):

You could try stb_image for reading and stb_image_write for writing. These are very small libraries.

http://nothings.org/
https://github.com/nothings/stb

---

Link to my question on gamedev I've got to know about this site:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9083/library-to-load-images-into-textures-linux-c-and-opengl

Answer (score 4):

I think FreeImage is the best one out there:

http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/

Comment: No FreeImage is a pure C library, although there is a C++ version called FreeImagePlus which wraps the C structs and functions in classes.

Comment: +1 freeimage, excellent library with good documentation

Answer (score 4):

[Simple Direct-media Layer (SDL)](http://www.libsdl.org/) with [SDL_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)

Comment: +1 For SDL.This is simple-advanced Library.from novice To Professional

Answer (score 3):

You could also just read and write raw image RGB values to a binary file, if that is really all you need, and if you know the image size ahead of time.

Comment: That's true. BMP and TGA file formats are also very simple to parse or generate.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to look at the [imagemagik c connector api](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php). It is very easy to get going, and the linked page has some nice code samples.

And there is always the [ubiquitous GD library](http://www.libgd.org/Basics). It is not hard to use either.

Answer (score 2):

I like gd. Real popular.

[link text](http://www.boutell.com/gd/)