# Selecting an icon from an image grid

Tags: c++, image-processing, image

I have a grid of icons and I want to select an individual icon and save it in separate image file. The image doesn't need to be processed further just simply split apart. Any thoughts on how to let the computer do this work for me?

[image: Icon Grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows, Bitmap::Clone will do it for you. [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.clone%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740535/simple-c-image-library