# Implementing machine learning algorithms on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, machine-learning

I wanted to try out machine learning algorithms on iOS - to start with say, linear regression. I was advised to use octave for the PC which would make stuff like matrix operations easier. I was wondering if I could find a library for the iOS to perform those operations.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks.

Edit:

To not sound vague, consider solving a linear regression problem which would involve computing transpose of a matrix, inverse of a matrix. I would be happy if I have a library with API's for it. openCV does have it but using it would be completely off context then.

Comment: Look for a C++ library - there are several open source ones. I've used several on the Mac several years ago but cannot find a link just now. With a C++ lib, you can interface to it using an objectives++ class. Not ideal but should work just fine.

Comment: I found the one I used - Eigen - http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your exact requirement on API's. But it guess it is possible to work with OpenCV on IOS and do variety of processing. 
For more information please check this link.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html

Once you have image in Mat format, i think you can carry out whole lot of operation. Also the one which you have listed.

Comment: Correct. The problem is openCV would be too heavy for the purpose.

Comment: Try looking into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816571/light-weight-c-image-library. I think you may want to try CImg, it supports MAC.

Comment: Seems I will have to experiment a bit. Thanks for the help.