# C++ Image File into an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there any way to take an image file (bmp, png, or something) and turn it into an array, or at least get the rgb value of a pixel? If not, can you tell me any good libraries to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support all kinds of formats, use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). OpenCV is a feature-rich (and correspondingly heavy-weight) tool suit for image-processing. It also comes with a whole bunch of datatypes, as well as image processing and vision tasks primitives.

If you prefer a light-weight alternative, I recommend [LodePNG](http://lodev.org/lodepng/) which only requires you to copy two files to get image read and write functionality. However, it only supports PNG and BMP. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816571/light-weight-c-image-library) discusses further alternatives. These alternatives usually just give you 2D arrays for images without proper datatypes or further processing tools.

Comment: There is [`Magick++`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) also.

Answer (score 1):

Use the OpenCV to read the image into a Mat object. And the you can get every pixel and its rgb value you want from Mat.

Comment: Could you please give me a link to that?

Comment: And what's a Mat object?

Comment: @user3055772  http://opencv.org/