# Read GrayScale image in array or matrix in c (Not using any library)

Tags: c, image

I want to read grayscale jpg image stored using opencv.
OpenCV code is

```
im = cv2.imread("cat.jpg", cv2.CV_8UC1)  
im = cv2.resize(im, (224, 224))  
cv2.imwrite("cat_8uc1.jpg", im)
```

I want to read this image as below

```
uint8_t image[294][294] = { all image data }
```

Do I need to convert this .jpg image into another format and use?

I want to read this image into 2D array/matrix in C not using any library.

Any Leads will be very helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C Image Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079/c-image-library)

Comment: hint: use a library

Comment: You need to do everything the library does for you. Read the file, decompress jpg into your array,  resize, compress to jpg again, write file.  Or you could use a library

Comment: I cannot use any library. I have to read file and play with it. I have tried reading file into binary file file but I could not decompose it into array. Any leads on how I can decompose this file into array?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using PGMA image format.
Thank you for your kind reply's.